# How to set the expiry on randomly generated alphanumeric coupon code using Java

Tags: java

I have written a Java program to provide discount using coupon that is automatically generated and I want to set expiry on it so that the coupon expires after 24 hours. And the next coupon code must be generated after 24 hours.

```java
public class Discount {

    public static void generateCouponCode() {
        String mycouponPattern = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int indexVal = (int)(mycouponPattern.length()*Math.random());
            stringBuffer.append(mycouponPattern.charAt(indexVal));
        }
        System.out.println("Coupon code generated successfully....");
        System.out.println("Your Generated coupon code is:"+stringBuffer.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Discount.generateCouponCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).
The below code uses class `java.time.LocalDateTime` to store the expiry date of the coupon. I changed class `Discount` to a [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/language/records.html#GUID-6699E26F-4A9B-4393-A08B-1E47D4B2D263). I added a [static] member `start` for generating the expiry dates for the generated coupons. Simply call method [plusHours](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusHours(long)) to add 24 hours. Method `main`, in the below code, calls method `generateCouponCode` twice to demonstrate that the expiry date in the first generated coupon is the current time plus 24 hours and the second generated coupon's expiry date is 48 hours after the current time.

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public record Discount(String coupon, LocalDateTime expires) {
    private static LocalDateTime  start = LocalDateTime.now();

    public static Discount generateCouponCode() {
        String mycouponPattern = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int indexVal = (int) (mycouponPattern.length() * Math.random());
            stringBuffer.append(mycouponPattern.charAt(indexVal));
        }
        System.out.println("Coupon code generated successfully....");
        start = start.plusHours(24L);
        Discount coupon = new Discount(stringBuffer.toString(), start);
        return coupon;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Discount.generateCouponCode());
        System.out.println(Discount.generateCouponCode());
    }
}
```

Output from a sample run of the above code:

```
Coupon code generated successfully....
Your Generated coupon code is:Q8HW5AIGHQ
Discount[coupon=Q8HW5AIGHQ, expires=2023-10-29T10:18:23.564755300]
Coupon code generated successfully....
Your Generated coupon code is:HEX57DHAE0
Discount[coupon=HEX57DHAE0, expires=2023-10-30T10:18:23.564755300]
```

##### EDIT

In response to OP [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378061/how-to-set-the-expiry-on-randomly-generated-alphanumeric-coupon-code-using-java/77378455#comment136413696_77378455), below code limits coupon generation to only after the last generated coupon has expired.

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public record Discount(String coupon, LocalDateTime expires) {
    private static LocalDateTime  start = LocalDateTime.now();

    public static Discount generateCouponCode() {
        if (LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(start)) {
            String mycouponPattern = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                int indexVal = (int) (mycouponPattern.length() * Math.random());
                stringBuffer.append(mycouponPattern.charAt(indexVal));
            }
            System.out.println("Coupon code generated successfully....");
            start = start.plusHours(24L);
            Discount coupon = new Discount(stringBuffer.toString(), start);
            return coupon;
        }
        else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Next coupon can be generated after: " + start);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Discount.generateCouponCode());
        System.out.println(Discount.generateCouponCode());
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
Coupon code generated successfully....
Discount[coupon=TK7SWLHMBM, expires=2023-10-29T12:23:36.342781700]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Next coupon can be generated after: 2023-10-29T12:23:36.342781700
    at basetest.Discount.generateCouponCode(Discount.java:22)
    at basetest.Discount.main(Discount.java:28)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your all efforts for writing the code for me and displaying the output. But how can I again change the code such that only one coupon code must be generated a day and the next coupon can be generated next day please can you give me a hint of that

Comment: How can I again change the code such that only one coupon code must be generated a day and the next coupon must be generated next day please can you give me a hint of that.

Comment: @StakiyoDcosta answer is edited.

Comment: Thankyou so much.Can you help me with other stuffs of Java please because I am a student I can send you the code which I have written for online shopping using JSE which I am facing dificulty in reading the file using ObjectInputStream.readObject() method

Comment: @StakiyoDcosta you can post more questions here, on SO. Just make sure you follow the guidelines in [ask] And thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: The above edited code is sometimes generating the coupon code that should generate the next day when I execute this code multiple times and sometimes both if and else block code executes can help me with this problem

Comment: When second time I execute the program after generating the coupon it should always give me an exception saying UnsupportedOperationException no untill the generated coupon expires